# Setting up Spock test with Allure reports

Tags: groovy, spock, allure

I have a test that runs on Spock framework. I am trying to setup Allure reports with it. I don't see an example for spock integration here https://github.com/allure-examples. So i took the Junit5 maven based example,https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit5-maven, and trying to set it up. I modified the dependency from

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>         
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>         
            <artifactId>allure-spock</artifactId>         
            <version>2.13.10</version>     
</dependency>
```

since i am using spock here to run the tests.

Below is the pom i am using,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <name>sample-test</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spock.version>2.0-M5-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.5.1</dbunit.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <geb.version>0.13.1</geb.version>
        <selenium.version>2.51.0</selenium.version>
        <groovy.version>3.0.8</groovy.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!--other repositories if any-->
        <repository>
            <id>project.local</id>
            <name>project</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/../repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!--mandatory for the groovy CLI scripts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mod4j.org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jankroken</groupId>
            <artifactId>commandline</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mandatory dependencies for using Spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mandatory dependencies for tests with DB interaction -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <!-- not scoped for test since Import/export use this library -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdb6</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON serialization/de-serialization library needed for JSONDataSet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- h2databse library used to query CSV files with SQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.191</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Geb testing support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.gebish</groupId>
            <artifactId>geb-spock</artifactId>
            <version>${geb.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- httpcomponents upgrade to fix error in HTMLUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium Web Driver Manager-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hadoop dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oozie dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>
            <artifactId>oozie-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hive dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
                    <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-site-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-spock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-spock</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0-M1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Mandatory plugins for using Spock -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn more about this plugin,
                visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Optional plugins for using Spock -->
            <!-- Only required if names of spec classes don't match default Surefire patterns (`*Test` etc.) -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <argLine>
                        -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.groovy</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <geb.build.reportsDir>target/test-reports/geb</geb.build.reportsDir>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                        <junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled>true</junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.13.10</reportVersion>
                    <resultsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</resultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

I am running a specific test class by using this command,

```
mvn -f pom.xml test -Dtest=CalcSpec -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore surefire-report:report
```

But i am getting this error while running it

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors (Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf (InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding (InjectorImpl.java:706)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:930)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.275 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-14T07:51:58-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project pic-test: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plu
gin:3.0.0-M5:test failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test: org/apache/maven/surefire/api/testset/TestSetFailedException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-plugin-3.0.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-surefire-provider/1.3.2/junit-platform-surefire-provider-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.0.0/apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.3.2/junit-platform-launcher-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-engine/1.3.2/junit-platform-engine-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-commons/1.3.2/junit-platform-commons-1.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/opentest4j/opentest4j/1.1.1/opentest4j-1.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-api/2.22.0/surefire-api-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-logger-api/2.22.0/surefire-logger-api-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-java5/2.22.0/common-java5-2.22.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.6/aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/3.0.0-M5/maven-surefire-common-3.0.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-extensions-api/3.0.0-M5/surefire-extensions-api-3.0.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/3.0.0-M5/surefire-booter-3.0.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-extensions-spi/3.0.0-M5/surefire-extensions-spi-3.0.0-M5.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-transfer/0.11.0/maven-artifact-transfer-0.11.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-common-artifact-filters/3.1.0/maven-common-artifact-filters-3.1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-java/1.0.5/plexus-java-1.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.2/asm-7.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/2.0-M9/qdox-2.0-M9.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-shared-utils/3.0.0-M4/surefire-shared-utils-3.0.0-M4.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/C:/Users/tji/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.surefire.api.testset.TestSetFailedException
```

What could be the issue here ? And is there any example out there for integrating Allure reports with Spock testing framework ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add *surefire-api* as an explicit dependency of the surefire plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-surefire-provider -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-api -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </dependency>
                ...
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```